# i just want to start my application from initial state 

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 activity when I press the image on 1 activity it launches the 2 activity. Each time when 2 activity launch it triggers the `http` request and form the table.

It works fine but when i press "back" button and then again start the application and came to the 2 activity.

It doesnt clear the previous data of table and add the data which came from http request. I didnt use a database its just a `xml` tablelayout.

Simply I just want to start my application from initial state.

I dont want the android system to remember the activity's previous state when I backpressed the whole application.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then may be i think you should completely close the application on back press so your problem will be solved.
this is the code :--

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() 
 {
    finish();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
 }
```

this method kills the application and Ofcourse your problem!

Answer (score 1):

In manifest, for second activity write `android:noHistory="true"`, then it won't remember history.

Comment: it doesnt work when i backpressed it remember the 2 activity's state and displays the previous data

Comment: @user1632100 You are talking about which activity 1 or 2.

Comment: im talking about 2nd activity.i want to completely close the application. so it doesnt remember the previous datea

Answer (score 0):

if i'm getting correct (from your question) , You need to check the views before making http call e.g let us say u have a textview there in table layout, then check like this before making the http call:

```
   if(getthevalueoftextview!=null){ 

           textview.setText("");
       }
```

Comment: its not table its tablelayout.pls help

Comment: what view have u used to display the form output just set text of that view to empty string do this stuff with in if else statement(see above). Let us say u have a textview to display the name then just assign empty string to that view by calling setText("") on that view

Comment: in short tablerow that was previously added by request is not being  cleared  when i press the back button and so when i again come to the activity it again request the data and added it in table layout with previous rows. getting my point??